# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Views.View' to 'int' on SetCustomView

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, xamarin.android

I am trying to set a custom view to my `ActionBar`'s `MenuItem`.

When I try to do the following:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
View mCustomeView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.spinnerlayout, null);

Spinner mspinner = mCustomeView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.home_spinner);
ArrayList mSpinnerOptions = new ArrayList();
mSpinnerOptions.Add("Stay");

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, mSpinnerOptions);
mspinner.Adapter = adapter;

ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
ActionBar.SetCustomView(mCustomeView, null);
```

I get an error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Android.Views.View' to 'int'

On the SetCustomView().

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Try this way ActionBar.SetCustomView(mCustomeView);

Comment: @Haresh tried that first. I got the same error

Comment: can you please post code of how you can initialize action bar or post whole code so i try to track your problem easily.

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock and MonoDroid? Maybe [this example](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ActionBarSherlock/ActionBarSherlockTest/FeatureToggles.cs) can help you. Also, is the method `ActionBar.SetCustomView(View, LayoutParams)` really available?

Comment: @AndrewT. Is there any other way I can add a drop down item to the Home button on ActionBarSherlock? I just want to display one item when the user clicks the Home button

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help since I never use neither (Action Bar's) Home button nor ActionBarSherlock.